# Supervisor FATAl Exited too quickly (process log may have details(About inet_http_server and unix_http_server)

Tags: django, linux, gunicorn, supervisord

I wrote a Django project and I use supervisor with gunicorn

`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf`

```
[group:weather_station]
programs=site

[program:site]
directory=$PROJECT
command=/home/nhcc/.local/bin/gunicorn -c /$PROJECT/weather_station/gunicorn.conf.py -p gunicorn.pod weather_station.wsgi
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor.log
environment=my-environment-variable
~
```

`sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl reload`

`sudo supervisorctl status`

It showed up the error

> weather_station:site             FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

So I checked out the log file :

`/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log`

> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,000 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,000 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/weather.conf" during parsing
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,007 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,008 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP
>   authentication checking
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,008 INFO RPC interface
>   'supervisor' initialized
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,008 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:25,008 INFO supervisord started with pid 32371
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:26,013 INFO spawned: 'site' with pid 32447
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:26,018 INFO exited: site (exit status 127; not expected)
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:27,022 INFO spawned: 'site' with pid 32448
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:27,026 INFO exited: site (exit status 127; not expected)
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:29,032 INFO spawned: 'site' with pid 32449
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:29,038 INFO exited: site (exit status 127; not expected)
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:32,043 INFO spawned: 'site' with pid 32451
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:32,059 INFO exited: site (exit status 127; not expected)
>
> 2017-09-08 17:15:33,060 INFO gave up: site entered FATAL state, too
>   many start retries too quickly

According to `Included extra file`[the solution](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/272)

According to `Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking`[the solution](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/717)

I added two section [unix_http_server] and [inet_http_server]

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0766                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))

[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=*:9001        ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface, 
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))
```

This is the current  supervisor.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0766                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
port=*:9001        ;

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/*.conf
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Then I ran

```
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

And I run

`sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl reload`

And I checked the log again

The error is completely be same

Does anyone know why??

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Did you check that running your gunicorn command outside of supervisor works? This kind of error may occur when the executed command fails.

Comment: HI @Jonathan have you resolve this issue, ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    # service supervisord stop
    # supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

and then check status with:

```
    # supervisorctl status
```